# Trigger a function in an App via HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, android, html

I wanted to implement in-app purchases to my web app without adding a side menu.
I use the RocketWeb Application Template for the Webapp found on codecanyon.

Is it possible to implement a trigger in the App and on the Website to make this happen:

User presses Button1 (HTML) that triggers a function in the App, and an In-app Purchase Modal pops up.
I want to do that because Google isn't too happy about adding direct payments.

The Modals n Co should be no problem, but I'm wondering if it's possible to "Bridge" App to Website basically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. You can `bridge` the Webview to your App -  [JS in WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript)

What you need to do:

1. Make sure JS is enabled in your WebView

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

2. Create JS listener interface, that can handle messages sent from the WebView:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void openPurchaceModal(String toast) {
        //TODO open your purchase screen using mContext as your context
    }
}
```

*Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript, and the method must be public. If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.*

3. Set your WebView's listener:

```
//Adds listener to the webView, under global JS object `Bridge` (You can use any name you want here)
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Bridge");
```

4. Use your `Bridge` object in JS inside the WebView, wherever you need it, like this:

```
 Bridge.openPurchaceModal();
```

You can have multiple methods defined in your listener, and call them like:

`Bridge.[method name]();`

You also can have primitive arguments like String, int, boolean etc' to these methods:

```
...
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
...
```

And use it:

`Bridge.showToast("toast text");`